# How to live overseas full-time as Australian aged pensioner, owning one Australian house

Tags: australia, pension

Would like to keep Australian house, rent out declare income and receive reduced pension.
Live outside Australia don't won't to spent 6M in and 6M out.
The 12 month outside Australia rule can be overcome by selling and buying house/unit overseas ( any country ) and declaring principle residence. Concerned about buying 1 million $AUD house in south east Asia where I live. Buying in Europe is secure but costly to live. I,m a nomad not wanting to be tied to a expensive home. What solutions are there beside selling up.

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re asking. Is your concern about your Australian pension https://www.servicesaustralia.gov.au/travel-outside-australia-rules-for-age-pension?context=22526? Or about *where* to live? Or about how much to spend on a house? Or about how to finance a nomad lifestyle?

Comment: Primarily to keep pension whilst living overseas. Having to sell your Australian  home just so you can live overseas is not my first choice. As one ages you may wish to return to Australia for medical care. If you sell your home, take the equity and buy overseas to keep Centrelink happy. You are then out of the Australia housing market, to get back in in 10 to 20 years time may be a struggle to keep up with Australian property values. Another option is to forgo the pension rent out house and live of income. Like most Australians you paid taxes and feel you deserve a old age pension.

Comment: One option seems to be to move to a country with which Australia has a social security agreement. How soon might you plan to move? You mention getting back into the market in 10-20 years? If that’s your timeframe your question becomes *much* harder to answer because of the risk of future changes to rules/agreements etc. If you sell to fund your lifestyle you’d also have an investment risk - where would you put your money to yield the income you need https://www.australiansuper.com/retirement/retirement-articles/2018/02/do-i-really-need-1-million-to-retire I suspect your question is too broad

Comment: Even if you live in one of the 31 agreement countries, your Australian house is considered a asset after being away for 12 months. I,m 63.5, pension age 67 so 3.5 years away. Yes selling up at 67, using that equity to buy overseas is risky in many ways. The 10-20 years I refer to is if your health failed and required good medical care in Oz. This means selling overseas house and buying back in Australia again. Who knows what pension rules will be in future. My rented house in Australia nets 25k same as full pension. That  has been my income the last 14 years of retirement. Want to stay o/s

Comment: You could downsize in Australia to stay within the limit? Such restrictions are common eg in the UK there’s no yearly increases if you live in certain countries. I think you should talk to a pensions/investment adviser.

Comment: Good advice, I have been trying. For years to find what you suggest here in Australia, had consultations to no avail. In Australia tax advice is just that, no financial planning. Financial planners are very well informed on Australian based matters, when talking about pension and living overseas they have no idea. Recently talked with wealth management 4 expats, cannot advise on pension matters. Truly there are 2 resources, government website ( I,m in a grey area ). And the International section of Centerlink, they can't legally tell you what to do just but do their best to explain the rules.